# How to pass the returned type as parameter to a new function (as if the function were be inside the return type)? js

Tags: javascript, function

Let's say that a hany any **object**, that return a string for example.
And I have the following:

```
function alterString(str){
    return `${str} was altered!`
}

//I want call my method as if it were be inside the return type
let new_string = object.returnString().alterString();
```

I've already did this in C#, but I don't even know the name to research

Comment: In C#, this is known as an [extension method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method). JS doesn't have these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String.prototype.alterString=function(){
  return `${this} was altered!`;
}
var obj = {
  returnString : function(){ return 'Hi'; }
};

let new_string = obj.returnString().alterString();
```

Or else you can add alterString() directly into returnString() as below.

```
var obj = {
   returnString : function(){
     this.text = "Hey";
   }
 };

 obj.returnString.prototype.alterString = function(){
   return `${this.text} was altered!`;
 }

 let new_string = new obj.returnString().alterString();
```

Comment: I thought there was a "direct way" (easier) rather than just assigning it to prototype, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Notice that the second approach doesn't "return a string", but instead builds a `returnString` instance. This is pretty confusing, avoid this pattern or use proper names.

Comment: I've realised this, the first one was definitely what i wanted!